# Estimating probability of winning for each player based on ranking data of previous tournaments

Tags: probability, bayesian, simulation, games, bradley-terry-model

The question could also be: "estimating the *true ability* of each player", though I think that already implies some assumptions.

[In this paper](http://www.ets.org/Media/Research/pdf/RM-15-03.pdf) I saw some references to Rankade and TrueSkill used by Microsoft, but I couldn't find any simple implementation for my relatively simple case.

Let's say there are 5 total players and I have data for

$$ t \in \{1, 2, 3 ..., T\} $$

tournaments. Each tournament has only data on the rankings for the people that played. For example:

```
 | rank | player |
    1      5
    2      3
    3      1
```

Note that not all players play in all tournaments.

**Assumptions I'm willing to make (but let me know if they're reasonable)**

- The skill of the players doesn't evolve
- The *observed skill* of player $i$ at tournament $t$ is some sort of true skill plus noise:

$$O_{it} = s_i + \varepsilon_{it} $$

Then the observed rankings are just the result of the rankings of $O_{it}$ for the players observed. I'm happy to make simplifying assumptions about $Cov(\varepsilon_{it}, \varepsilon_{jt})$ and $Cov(\varepsilon_{it}, \varepsilon_{i(t-1)})$. These cross-terms could be assumed to be zero.

I think one possibility is to go bayesian: start with a prior on $s_i$ (assume they have the same mean and variance) and then to update, but I'm not sure how to proceed with this.

**My specific objetive**

Coming with a code/estimation/simulation procedure that allows me to predict a ranking after observing $T$ tournaments. Getting confidence intervals is nice but not necessary. Getting a closed-form solution would be great, but I doubt I'll get there.

**My (unfortunately still rather vague) question for you**

How would you approach this? 
@Glen_b in the comments suggested a Bradley-Terry model (which has an [`R` implementation](https://www.jstatsoft.org/article/view/v012i01/v12i01.pdf)

If I get it right, these models run with pairwise data. That is, given my data above like

```
 | rank | player |
    1      5
    2      3
    3      1
```

I would have to transform this data to  `player_5 > player_3`, `player_5 > player_1` and `player_3 > player_1` ?

Comment: You might want to investigate Bradley-Terry models. The brief discussion at the start of [this article](https://www.jstatsoft.org/article/view/v012i01/v12i01.pdf) seems to give the gist of it. There are a number of questions already on site (a few even in the sidebar -> ) that are relevant to your question (or to Bradley-Terry models). Those are not the only relevant thing you could be looking at but it might be useful to you.

Comment: @Glen_b Thanks! I'll update the question with the info you provide